# LINQ Nested Where

Tags: linq

If I have the following model;

```
  public List<RecommendedProduct> recommendations
```

Then

```
public class RecommendedProduct
  public List<Product> Products
```

Then the Product;

```
public class Product
  public string Code
```

The **recommendations** list has, as an example, 10 items in it.

Each **recommendations** item has two Products in it.

How, with LINQ, can I find the **recommendations** object that has products with both "A" and "B" product codes?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the `Any` extension:

```
var myProducts =
    from rp in recommendations
    where
        cp.Products.Any(p => p.Product.Code == "A") &&
        cp.Products.Any(p => p.Product.Code == "B")
    select rp;
```

`Any` returns `true` if there are any elements in the sequence that match the inner condition.  In this case you're searching for two elements, so it takes two `Any` calls.