# LINQ Next Item in List

Tags: linq

Taking a look at my question [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680085/linq-nested-where), I now want to return the next **recommendation** object (after) the one that matches the criteria.

So say I found item 6 out of 10, I'd like the query to return item 7 instead.

Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since you have a `List<T>` object you can use its `FindIndex` method instead of `Where` to get the index of the first matching item rather than the item itself:

```
int index = recommendations.FindIndex(rp =>
                                            rp.Products.Any(p => p.Product.Code == "A") 
                                         && rp.Products.Any(p => p.Product.Code == "B")
                                      );
```

Once you have the index you can get the next item or previous item or whatever you want.

Answer (score 55):

Here's my current best method:

```
MyList.SkipWhile(item => item.Name != "someName").Skip(1).FirstOrDefault()
```

An earlier answer uses `Skip(1).Take(1)` which works, but returns a list of one result. In my case (and perhaps the OP's case), we're looking for the actual item. So my code skips until it gets to the one we're looking for (a Where would return a subset so we wouldn't have access to the next item) then skips one more and then gets the item.

Comment: Note:  This answer is mentioned in the Microsoft Virtual Academy course 'De-Mystifying LINQ'  - Part 6

Comment: This should be the answer.

Answer (score 17):

Try this one

---

**NEXT Item**

```
MyList.SkipWhile(x => x != value).Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();
```

**PREVIOUS Item** note:Reverse() will not work for LINQ to SQL

```
 var MyList2 = MyList.ToList();
 MyList2.Reverse();
 MyList2.SkipWhile(x => x != value).Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I think `Reverse` is not implemented in SQL Server.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358497(v=vs.110).aspx It is LINQ and Reverse is here

Comment: Yes, it's LINQ API, but if it's LINQ to SQL (Server), it will throw error, because there is no equivalence in SQL.

Comment: Yes! you are right it will throw an error in case of LINQ to SQL.but i dont think here we are talking about LINQ to SQL. Let me edit my answer so people should know about it.

Comment: Works perfectly with `ICollection<T>`. I adapted this to get only one result, with an object: `list.SkipWhile(x => !x.Equals(myObject)).Skip(1).Take(1).SingleOrDefault()`.

Answer (score 7):

How about something like this:

```
public static class Extension
{
    public static T Next<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        bool flag = false;

        using (var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
        {
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                if (flag) return enumerator.Current;

                if(predicate(enumerator.Current))
                {
                    flag = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

You could then call it like you would for Where

```
Products.Next(x => x.Whatever);
```

Answer (score 1):

This *should* do it. I haven't constructed a test for it specifically.

```
var nextProducts = from item1 in recommendations.Select((rec, idx) => new { Rec = rec, Index = idx })
                    join item2 in recommendations.Select((rec, idx) => new { Rec = rec, Index = idx })
                    on item1.Index equals item2.Index - 1
                    where item1.Rec.Products.Any(p => p.Code == "A")
                    && item1.Rec.Products.Any(p => p.Code == "B")
                    select item2.Rec;
```

If you needed both records, the select statement could be

```
select new { MatchingItem = item1.Rec, NextItem = item2.Rec };
```

But then you would have to do a grouping to account for a matching item being the last item in the list (there would not be a next item in that case).

```
var nextProducts = from item1 in recommendations.Select((rec, idx) => new { Rec = rec, Index = idx })
                    join item2 in recommendations.Select((rec, idx) => new { Rec = rec, Index = idx })
                    on item1.Index equals item2.Index - 1
                    into groupjoin
                    from i2 in groupjoin.DefaultIfEmpty ()
                    where item1.Rec.Products.Any(p => p.Code == "A")
                    && item1.Rec.Products.Any(p => p.Code == "B")
                    select new { MatchingItem = item1.Rec, NextItem = i2 == null ? null : i2.Rec };
```

The code I *did* test was something similar with a list of strings.

```
List<string> list = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c", "a", "d", "a", "e" };

var query = from item1 in list.Select((s, idx) => new { Item = s, Index = idx })
            join item2 in list.Select((s, idx) => new { Item = s, Index = idx })
            on item1.Index equals item2.Index - 1
            where item1.Item == "a"
            select item2.Item;
```

Which returns b, d, and e.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that:

- the item is unique in the list
- the item is gotten from the same list
- there is the next item

you can get the next item this way

```cs
myList[myList.IndexOf(item) + 1];
// or
myList.ElementAt(myList.IndexOf(item) + 1);
```

If you're not sure there is the next item you can use `try` + `catch` or:

```cs
myList.ElementAtOrDefault(myList.IndexOf(item) + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is item 7 a match to your Where clause?  If so, use the `Skip()` and `Take()` extension methods:

```
var myProducts =
   from rp in recommendations
   where
      cp.Products.Any(p => p.Product.Code == "A") &&
      cp.Products.Any(p => p.Product.Code == "B")
   select rp;

var nextProduct = myProducts.Skip(1).Take(1);
```

Comment: I dont think this will exactly work. In the OPs case it would seem that the original would only return 1 result, and they want the next in the ORIGINAL list.

Comment: @spoulson, that's correct. I want to find the matching item and then return the next item in the list.