# Linq way to get piecewise difference between element and next element in list

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a Linq way of knowing what the next element in the sequence is while iterating? As a concrete example, say I have a list of ints, and I want to calculate the difference between each element and its successor, so for example I would like to be able to write

```
var myList = new List<int>() { 1,3,8,2,10 };
var differences = myList.Select( ml => ml.Next() - ml ) // pseudo-code, obviously
```

where the result I want is a list { 2,5,-6,8 }.

Obviously this is trivial in a for loop, but can anyone think of a neat one-liner in Linq to do this job?

Comment: this question might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680228/linq-next-item-in-list

Answer (score 50, accepted):

If you're using .NET 4 then you could [`Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) and [`Skip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx):

```
var differences = myList.Zip(myList.Skip(1), (x, y) => y - x);
```

If you're using an older version of the framework, and/or you wanted a *slightly* more efficient way of doing this, then you could create a simple extension method:

```
var differences = myList.Pairwise((x, y) => y - x);

// ...

public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Pairwise<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, T, T> selector)
    {
        if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        if (selector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("selector");

        using (var e = source.GetEnumerator())
        {
            if (!e.MoveNext()) throw new InvalidOperationException("Sequence cannot be empty.");

            T prev = e.Current;

            if (!e.MoveNext()) throw new InvalidOperationException("Sequence must contain at least two elements.");

            do
            {
                yield return selector(prev, e.Current);
                prev = e.Current;
            } while (e.MoveNext());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Love it; it's exactly what I would have answered had I known a Zip() function existed.

Comment: @Keith Or you could use it from MoreLinq for .NET 3.5.

Comment: The only minor drawback of this solution is that myList will be enumerated twice. Can be easily fixed though with Memoize method from Reactive Extensions for .NET (Rx).

Answer (score 7):

```
var differences = myList
    .Take(myList.Count - 1)
    .Select((v, i) => myList[i + 1] - v);
```

Assuming the list has at least 2 items.

Comment: Please, be aware that this solution works on indexed lists only, while the Zip solution (given in https://stackoverflow.com/a/3970131/637968) works on generic IEnumerable sequences.