# Get next item in list c# and update the current one

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list like this

```
List<NamazTimesModel> res = nt.Select();
```

In res I have data like this

```
[
{
"name": "fajr",
"salahTime": "05:23",
"namazTime": "05:23",
"date": "3/6/2017 12:00:00 AM",
"endTime": null
},
{
"name": "sunrise",
"salahTime": "07:01",
"namazTime": "07:01",
"date": "3/6/2017 12:00:00 AM",
"endTime": null
},
{
"name": "zuhr",
"salahTime": "12:33",
"namazTime": "12:33",
"date": "3/6/2017 12:00:00 AM",
"endTime": null
},
....
]
```

I am looping over the list and checking what is the current item. For example it is 'fajr' then I have to take the next item and get the 'salahTime' from there and set 'endTime' of fajr to be that.

Can I get some help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ Next Item in List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680228/linq-next-item-in-list)

Comment: care to include how exactly you are looping through the list?

Comment: @NineBerry I think OP wants slightly more than his title says: he needs the current item, in addition to the next one, so that he could modify its properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
   var res = nt.Aggregate(new List<NamazTimesModel>(), (t, i) =>
            {
                if (t.Count > 0)
                {
                    t[t.Count - 1].endTime = i.salahTime;
                }
                t.Add(i);
                return t;
            }
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can skip list items while your target item is not found, then grab the target item itself, along with the next one:

```
var twoItems = res.SkipWhile(item => item.Name != "fajr").Take(2).ToList();
```

If you have exactly two items in `twoItems` list, then you found `fajr`, and it wasn't the last item on the list. If you have fewer than two items, then either `fajr` wasn't there, or it was the last item on the list.

Check that you have two items, and set fields as necessary:

```
if (twoItems.Count == 2) {
    twoItems[0].EndTime = twoItems[1].SalahTime;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 1; i < res.Count; i++)
{
   // Todo: Check for null references by your own way.
   res[i - 1].endTime = res[i].salahTime;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set Namaz times as below,

```
for(var i = 0; i<nts.Count()-1; i++){
 nt[i].EndTime = nt[i+1].SalahTime
}
```

Then don't forget to set last Namaz time:

```
nts[nt.Count()-1] = nts[0].SalahTime;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
res.ForEach(item =>
{
     int index = res.FindIndex(m => m.name == item.name);
     item.endTime = index+1 != res.Count ? res.ElementAt(index + 1).salahTime : res.FirstOrDefault().salahTime;
});;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do two iterations with linq query.

It will be like this:

`string[] numbers= {"one","two","last"};
string[] variables={"string one","int two","string three"};
var res = variables.Where(v => numbers.Any(n => v.Contains(n
    )));
res.ToList().ForEach(d => Console.WriteLine(d));`

working code [here](http://csharppad.com/gist/4ac5ba0c8bac61d47a2548fbbb5233c3).